# How to save the notification title or body in background without clicking on it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an app in which I have to save all the notification coming from the server using firebase. I can save which notification is coming in the foreground and also I can save if notification is coming in the background but in a condition that if I clicked on the notification I can able to save it. But my main concern is if the user swipes the notification or clear the notification that means a user will not click on the notification, then how can I save it. Is there any method? Please help me to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a class that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` so you can do stuff on the `onMessageReceived` function. You can use the RemoteMessage function `getData()` see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) to ge the message payload. From there you can access the title and other information. Of course you'll need to know about the structure of the notification received. So, to answer you question you can save the notification information when it is received in the background by simply saving it in the `onMessageReceived` method of your `FirebaseMessagingService`.

FCM stops receiving notifications when the app is killed [see](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/378). So your best approach is to do as @D10S suggested and implement the saving and the sending in cloud functions. [here's](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) an example of how to send notifications. You'll need to make your app save the notification token to the real time database so the cloud function can read it and send the notification to the correct user.

To save your token to the Real Time database you'll need to add some code in your `FirebaseInstanceIdService`, specially in the `onTokenRefresh` method. You can have a location in your database called **tokens** and you can create an object with the user ID. So you could add the token to the server like so:

```
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("tokens");
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put(userUID, token);
ref.setValueAsync(users);
```

Comment: By using onMessageReceived only I saved notification in the foreground but in the background, I am not able to save it. I have already put a log and it is not showing.

Comment: how can I make my app to save the notification token to the real-time DB?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications which are coming from server will be received in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` , From `remoteMessage` object  you will get `title` and `body` , which you can store in sqlite or in SharedPreference.
   For Example:-

```
  class FBMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i("PVL", "MESSAGE RECEIVED!!");
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.i("PVL", "RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        } else {
            Log.i("PVL", "RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        }
    }
}
```

`onMessageReceived` will get event in every state :-Killed ,background,foreground.

Comment: I have already done that Vivek but I am not able to see anything in Log when application is in background

Comment: it seems that your server side code is missing some point.
In which language is your server side code for sending notification ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not save the notification if the user doesn't open it in the app, so if he swipes the notification there is no way to save it within the app.

An option is use Cloud Functions for Firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

So you can create a function that send notification to your users, and then add code to add the behaviour that you are looking for: when you send a notification, save it.

Comment: Are you sure we cannot save? @D10S

Comment: I could be wrong but If the user doesn't open the app, I can not see the way to save the notification with code in the app, because the code never would be triggered. That is why I am using Cloud Functions because it save the notification even if the user never opens the app.

Comment: Hii @D10S , your are wrong ,we can save data even if user doesn't open the app. I have practically done.

Comment: Hi @VivekPatel, I tried your code, and this code is  working fine if the app is in foreground when it receives a notification or if the user clicks into the notification. However is not working if the app is in background and the user doesn't click the notification.

Answer (score 0):

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

```
val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "sent phone: ${remoteMessage.from}")
    if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title, remoteMessage.notification?.body)
    }
}

private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
    val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
    // sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val intent = Intent(this, MenuscreenActivity::class.java)
    databaseHelper.insertData(title, body, databaseHelper.FIRST_TABLE_NAME)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    startActivity(intent)
    val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

```
val TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService"

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "sent phone: ${remoteMessage.from}")
    if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage.notification?.title, remoteMessage.notification?.body)
    }
}

private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
    val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
    // sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val intent = Intent(this, MenuscreenActivity::class.java)
    databaseHelper.insertData(title, body, databaseHelper.FIRST_TABLE_NAME)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    startActivity(intent)
    val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

}